# apply map function requiring two integers to a list of lists

Tags: python, function

Would like to try and apply the map function to this triangle_area formula using each 2 integer pair form this lists of lists. Returning an error that I am missing one of the required variables "h".

```
# map function

def area_triangle(b,h):
    area =  b*h/2
    return area

lists = [[4,5], [2,3], [11,45]]

list(map(area_triangle, lists))
```

[image]

Comment: Please read the [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on using images in questions and update your question appropriately. Though you may have your answer, it can help others with similar questions find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is precisely what `itertools.starmap` is for:

```
import itertools

list(itertools.starmap(area_triangle, lists)) # [10.0, 3.0, 247.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the arguments `b` and `h` to the map.

## map function

```
def area_triangle(b,h):
    area =  b*h/2
    return area

lists = [[4,5], [2,3], [11,45]]
b = [item[0] for item in lists]
h = [item[1] for item in lists]
list(map(area_triangle, b,h))
[10.0, 3.0, 247.5]
```